# Проблема со step by step переходами

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеются так называемые step by step переходы. Проблема заключается в том что, из-за прозрачного фона, вкладки накладываются друг на друга образуя кашу. (прозрачный фон задуман с самого начала, смена цвета фона не подходит). Хотелось бы получить помощь, можно ли сделать так что бы после открытия следующей вкладки, предыдущие вкладки скрывались. В javascript'e вообще не силен.

Сами вкладки - `codepen.io/bulsix/pen/oExpeX/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо вашего js

```js
$('#myBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('#myModal')
    .show(0)
    .find('.modal-bodies > .modal-body')
      .eq(0)
      .addClass('is-showing');
});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $('#myModal')
    .hide(0)
    .find('.modal-bodies > .modal-body')
    .removeClass('is-showing');
});

$('#myModal .button').on('click', function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents('.modal-body');

  if( parent.is(':last-child') ) {
    // Код, который сработает после клика Verify Now
    return false;
  }

  parent
    .removeClass('is-showing')
    .next('.modal-body')
    .addClass('is-showing');
});
```